# How to make a query that have Union and join in one query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to make a query that have Union and join in one query and I get error on this.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    reg_tblvetspecialization 
WHERE   pig = 1 
UNION 
SELECT  * 
FROM    reg_tblvetspecialization 
WHERE   chicken = 1 
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  a.system_md_id, a.firstname, a.middlename, 
                a.lastname, a.suffixname, a.profession, a.date_issue, 
                b.Province, b.Municipality, 
                b.company_clinic_name,  b.system_clinic_name_id 
        FROM    reg_tblveterinarian a 
                INNER JOIN reg_tblcliniccompany b 
                    ON a.system_md_id = b.system_md_id 
        WHERE   a.system_md_id = 20041708  
                AND a.deleted = 0 
        GROUP BY a.system_md_id
    );
```

Comment: Why don't you change the filter to where pig=1 or chicken=1 then you won't need Union at all

Comment: well, it's difficult to answer you. Folks here are not mind readers. You have to specify the relationship between the tables. And it would be much better if you can provid sample data and required output along with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some issues with your query:

- No join criteria for the **LEFT JOIN**. So Add one.
- No alias for the right table in the **LEFT JOIN**. Set one.

That said, your query should look like:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    reg_tblvetspecialization 
WHERE   pig = 1 
UNION 
SELECT  * 
FROM    reg_tblvetspecialization 
WHERE   chicken = 1 
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  a.system_md_id, a.firstname, a.middlename, 
                a.lastname, a.suffixname, a.profession, a.date_issue, 
                b.Province, b.Municipality, 
                b.company_clinic_name,  b.system_clinic_name_id 
        FROM    reg_tblveterinarian a 
                INNER JOIN reg_tblcliniccompany b 
                    ON a.system_md_id = b.system_md_id 
        WHERE   a.system_md_id = 20041708  
                AND a.deleted = 0 
        GROUP BY a.system_md_id
    ) d                     --adding alias
ON reg_tblvetspecialization.common_column=d.common_column; --adding a join condition
```